# Few x-values contribute to hard-to-read y-values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a geom_bar and apparently for some few x-values the y-value is very high, leading to the majority of bars to be at the bottom of the plot.

Is there a way to ignore these "outlier" y-values so that my y-axis scale is within the range of the majority of x-values?

This is a facet_wrap, so I cannot hard-set the y-axis limits.

```
  ggplot(test, aes(position,rowSums)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~NCBI, scales = "free", ncol = 4) + theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove them from your dataset like `df_plot <- df[rowSums < 1000, ]`

Comment: scale_y_log10() might help

Comment: "I cannot hard-set the y-axis limits".  Yes you can.  `coord_cartesian()` works perfectly well with `facte_wrap()`.

Comment: I cannot because it will differ for each individual facet how I should set the limits